# Git asks "please tell me who you are". Unable to auto detect email address?

Tags: node.js

Console log error :

```
please tell me who you are
```

I run this:

```
git config  _ _global user.email"you@example.com"
git config  _ _global user.email"you@example.com"
```

to set. your accounts default identity.
Omit `_ _ global` to set the identity only in this repository.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` you need two dashes, together with no space in between before global. Your code has underscores with a space in between. You should also have a space in between `user.email` and `"you@example.com"`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is also not a place to make fun of new users. Yes, the question title is bad, and the question itself should probably be closed as simple **typo** problem. But making a lame joke here is the wrong reaction. Instead, go in, change the question title and do a reasonable close vote.

Comment: @GhostCat I genuinely thought this was a (really stupid) phishing attempt, given the title and text of the post, and responded accordingly with a close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe" // config name, don't for your question
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Use `--global` insteal of `_ _global`

Check [Getting Started - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

If you want set for just that repository, you should modify `.git/config`.
`--global` set global config, not just one repository.